# How do I style regular (untagged) HTML text with CSS?

Tags: html, css

So I just started learning HTML and CSS like 2 days ago and I ran into a problem. I'm creating a cheat sheet for myself and all the CSS text indentations applies only to my h2 tags no matter what I do.

```
<section>
    <!-- Bold, Italics, Underline -->
    <h2>Bold, Italics, and Underline</h2>
    <strong>&ltstrong&gt;</strong> The strong tag is used to <strong>bolden</strong> text.
    <br>
    <strong>&lt;em&gt;</strong> The em tag is used to <em>italicise</em> text.
    <br>
    <strong>&lt;u&gt;</strong> The u tag is used to <u>underline</u> text.
  </section>
```

This is the way I've written my code, I sectioned my lines based on relevant tags and put all of them in a div with a container class. In my CSS stylesheet, I was playing around with `text-indent` and found that no matter where I place it, it only applies to my h2 tags.

I've tried nesting that command within different CSS classes, removing all my sections and just keeping my text in the div, etc but nothing works. I didn't want to use paragraph tags for each line of text because of the padding which is why I used regular text.

Comment: "*I didn't want to use paragraph tags for each line of text because of the padding.*" Using `<p>` tags is the correct element for text in HTML. You need to use block and inline elements appropriately. If you don't like the padding, then change it using CSS! Its a lot simpler (as well as being the correct way) than trying to write more complicated CSS to style the text when it isn't in an appropriate block element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/pr_text_text-indent.asp) about `text-indent` stated:

> Definition and Usage
>
> The text-indent property specifies the indentation of the first line in a text-block.

As for what counts as a text block, you can find it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_blocks.asp).

Or you can move the section by using the CSS `margin-left` style.

Example:

```html
<section style="margin-left: 12px;">
  <strong>This is Indented with margin</strong>
  <br>
  Lorem consectetur mollit proident ad quis commodo pariatur ullamco mollit eiusmod cupidatat amet fugiat.
</section>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<section>
  <strong>This is unindented</strong>
  <br>
  Lorem consectetur mollit proident ad quis commodo pariatur ullamco mollit eiusmod cupidatat amet fugiat.
</section>
```

Comment: Alright! That worked, thanks so much!

Comment: @EbenezerZergabachew there's no need to say "thank you" in the comment. You just need to [vote and accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer.